# Apply timeout control around Java operation

Tags: java, timeout

I'm using a third party Java library to interact with a REST API. The REST API can sometimes take a long time to respond, eventually resulting in a `java.net.ConnectException` being thrown.

I'd like to shorten the timeout period but have no means of modifying the third party library.

I'd like to apply some form of timeout control around the calling of a Java method so that I can determine at what point to give up waiting.

This doesn't relate directly to network timeouts. I'd like to be able to try and perform an operation and be able to give up after a specified wait time.

The following is by no means valid Java but does conceptually demonstrate what I'd like to achieve:

```
try {
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    entity.methodThatMakesUseOfRestApi();
} catch (<it's been ages now, I don't want to wait any longer>) {
    throw TimeoutException();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend [TimeLimiter](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.java) from Google Guava library.

Comment: This is awesome! I was looking for this.

Comment: Some examples of using the TimeLimiter can be found at https://code.google.com/r/rodneytt-guava/source/browse/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiterTest.java

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the current way how this should be done with plain Java:

```
public String getResult(final RESTService restService, String url) throws TimeoutException {
    // should be a field, not a local variable
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    // Java 8:
    Callable<String> callable = () -> restService.getResult(url);

    // Java 7:
    // Callable<String> callable = new Callable<String>() {
    //     @Override
    //     public String call() throws Exception {
    //         return restService.getResult(url);
    //     }
    // };

    Future<String> future = threadPool.submit(callable);
    try {
        // throws a TimeoutException after 1000 ms
        return future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no general timeout mechanism valid for arbitrary operations.

While... there is one... by using Thread.stop(Throwable). It works and it's thread safe, but your personal safety is in danger when the angry mob confronts you.

```
// realizable 
try
{
    setTimeout(1s);  // 1
    ... any code     // 2 
    cancelTimeout(); // 3
}
catch(TimeoutException te)
{
    // if (3) isn't executed within 1s after (1)
    // we'll get this exception
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but have to downvote this. Claiming this is safe is in complete contradiction to reality. ***"This method is inherently unsafe"*** - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop(java.lang.Throwable)

Answer (score 2):

Now we have our nice CompletableFuture , here an application to achieve what was asked.

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::foo).get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and a [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help in stopping an ongoing operation?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a utility class I wrote, which should do the trick unless I've missed something. Unfortunately it can only return generic Objects and throw generic Exceptions. Others may have better ideas on how to achieve this.

```
public abstract class TimeoutOperation {

long timeOut = -1;
String name = "Timeout Operation"; 

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getTimeOut() {
    return timeOut;
}

public void setTimeOut(long timeOut) {
    this.timeOut = timeOut;
}

public TimeoutOperation (String name, long timeout) {
    this.timeOut = timeout;
}

private Throwable throwable;
private Object result;
private long startTime;

public Object run () throws TimeoutException, Exception {
    Thread operationThread = new Thread (getName()) {
        public void run () {
            try {
                result = doOperation();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throwable = ex;
            } catch (Throwable uncaught) {
                throwable = uncaught;
            }
            synchronized (TimeoutOperation.this) {
                TimeoutOperation.this.notifyAll();
            }   
        }
        public synchronized void start() {
            super.start();
        }
    };
    operationThread.start();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    synchronized (this) {
        while (operationThread.isAlive() && (getTimeOut() == -1 || System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + getTimeOut())) {
            try {
                wait (1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }   
    }   
    if (throwable != null) {
        if (throwable instanceof Exception) {
            throw (Exception) throwable;
        } else if (throwable instanceof Error) {
            throw (Error) throwable;
        }   
    }   
    if (result != null) {
        return result;
    }   
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > startTime + getTimeOut()) {
        throw new TimeoutException("Operation '"+getName()+"' timed out after "+getTimeOut()+" ms");
    } else {
        throw new Exception ("No result, no exception, and no timeout!");
    }
}

public abstract Object doOperation () throws Exception;

public static void main (String [] args) throws Throwable {
    Object o = new TimeoutOperation("Test timeout", 4900) {
        public Object doOperation() throws Exception {
            try {
                Thread.sleep (5000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            return "OK";
        }
    }.run();
    System.out.println(o);
}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static final int NUM_TRIES =4;
    int tried =0;
    boolean result =false;
    while (tried < NUM_TRIES && !result)
    {
    try {
        Entity entity = new Entity();

            result = entity.methodThatMakesUseOfRestApi();


    }  
     catch (<it's been ages now, I don't want to wait any longer>) {
        if ( tried == NUM_TRIES)
        {
           throw new TimeoutException();
        }

    }
                tried++;
            Thread.sleep(4000);
  }
```